# How to merge/combine the value of two rows within a Series when the two rows' values are different?

Tags: python, pandas, slice, series

I have a Pandas Series which contains one Index column and a second column, 0.

The Index Column contains several abbreviations for languages. Two different values in this Index column are "en" for "English" and "en-gb" for "British English." There are numerous other values in this column including "es" for "Spanish, "fr" for "French," and so on.

So the Series looks something like this:

```
Index      0

en         42000
en-gb      500
es         320
und        143
fr         50
```

The column, 0, contains a value for the number of times each language value from the Index column appears in the original dataframe.

**What I'm trying to do is to combine two values for "en" and "en-gb" such that they are counted as one.**

And I want a new Series that looks like this:

```
Index      0

en         42500
es         320
und        143
fr         50
```

**EDIT:** Suggestions are telling me to modify the original DataFrame. The problem with this suggestion is that I don't have a traditional dataframe as the source of my Pandas Series.

Instead, the origin of my Pandas Series is a list of dictionaries, and within those dictionaries, one of the keys is ANOTHER dictionary.

So to be clear I have: A list of thousands of dictionaries.

One of the keys for each dictionary is "user."

The value for the "user" key is ANOTHER dictionary.

Within that second dictionary there is a key "lang" and values like "en," "en-gb," "es," "fr,", and so on.

So visually, I guess a sample of my original data looks like this:

```
list_of_things = [
{'id':4444, 'user': {'lang':'en', 'gibberish':'*#(#($&'}, 'location':'USA'},

{'id':555, 'user': {'lang':'fr', 'gibberish':'*#(#($&'}, 'location':'France'}, 

{'id':666, 'user': {'lang':'en-gb', 'gibberish':'*#(#($&'}, 'location':'Great Britain'}, 

{'id':777, 'user': {'lang':'en', 'gibberish':'*#(#($&'}, 'location':'USA'}, 

{'id':888, 'user': {'lang':'en', 'gibberish':'*#(#($&'}, 'location':'USA'}, {'id':999, 'user': {'lang':'en', 'gibberish':'*#(#($&'}, 'location':'USA'},

{'id':888, 'user': {'lang':'en', 'gibberish':'*#(#($&'}, 'location':'USA'}, {'id':999, 'user': {'lang':'en', 'gibberish':'*#(#($&'}, 'location':'USA'},
{'id':888, 'user': {'lang':'en', 'gibberish':'*#(#($&'}, 'location':'USA'}, {'id':999, 'user': {'lang':'es', 'gibberish':'*#(#($&'}, 'location':'Spain'},
{'id':888, 'user': {'lang':'en-gb', 'gibberish':'*#(#($&'}, 'location':'Great Britain'}, {'id':999, 'user': {'lang':'und', 'gibberish':'*#(#($&'}, 'location':'Unknown'},
]
```

Comment: you want to keep two `es` separately  ?

Comment: Ah, sorry, that's a mistake I made in creating my table here -- I already have only one instance of es.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df.groupby(df['Index'].str[:2])['0'].sum()
```

or

```
df.groupby(df['Index'].str.split('-').str[0])['0'].sum()
```

You get

```
Index
en    42500
es      320
fr       50
un      143
```

Comment: @Wen, hmmm, doesnt make much sense though

Comment: Ah, sorry, that's a mistake I made in creating my table here -- I already have only one instance of es.

Comment: LOL, he change it :-)

Comment: I updated my question to reflect that I can't modify my data using this method (because I don't have a traditional DataFrame as the source of my data).